# Send Mail in HTML Format using mvc

Tags: c#, html, email, model-view-controller, html-email

I need to send the mail in HTML Format. I googled lot but i could not able to get the expected result as html format. Can anyone help what i am missing in this following code to get the html format mail.

### C# Code

```
         MailAddress sender = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpUser"]);
             string MailId = Convert.ToString(Session["EmailID"]);
     SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient()
                    {
                        Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"],
                        Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"]),
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                        EnableSsl = true,
                        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPass"]),
                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
                    };
  System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                string text = "<table><tr><td>EmpId</td><td>Emp name</td><td>age</td></tr><tr><td>value</td><td>value</td><td>value</td></tr></table>";
                msg.From = sender;
                msg.To.Add(MailId);
                msg.Body = text;                
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Subject = "Password Credentials"; 
 smtp.Send(mail.From, mail.To, mail.Subject, msg.Body);
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: `msg.IsBodyHtml = true;` should be all you need. What result are you getting?

Comment: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/send-email-using-html-template-or-html-formatted-email-in-Asp-Net-1091.aspx

Comment: @Willy i am getting the text format result not html format

Comment: <html>
    <head>
<title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<table>
<tr>
<td> Dear, <p>yourname</p></td>
   <td><br /></td>

<td> Your Password has been created.</td>
</tr>
</table>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: What mail client are you using?

Comment: @Kamo Im using gmail

Comment: Shouldn't your body be `HtmlString`, not typical `string`?

Comment: @kamo i was changed the code instead of using string data i am using streamreader to read the html file in my application but yet i got the same text format of result..

Comment: @dinesh.k - reading HTML doesn't mean the string is HTML - for most cases if you want C# to treat string as HTML it has to be converted to `HtmlString`. Using `StreamReader` gives you `string` as output, not string formatted as HTML.

Comment: @kamo http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/send-email-using-html-template-or-html-formatted-email-in-Asp-Net-1091.aspx

Comment: @dinesh.k - yeah but this is still as I said - using `StreamReader` doesn't give you formatted HTML as output. In this example it works because `Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;` flag is set :)

Comment: System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();                
                msg.From = sender;
                msg.To.Add(MailId);
                var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Views/sendmail.html");
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, true);
                string readfile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                string strcontent = "";
                strcontent = readfile;
                msg.Body = strcontent;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

Comment: @kamo Is there any way to get string to htmlstring... But i too set the IsBodyHtml= true...

Comment: @dinesh.k - you can just use `new HtmlString(your_string).ToHtmlString()` as last resort but I am not sure it will help. Just try :)

Comment: Finally i found the answer i was simply send the smpt.send(msg) instead of smtp.Send(mail.From, mail.To, mail.Subject, msg.Body);  @kamo thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Not fully working example, but a hint is given below:

var msg = new MailMessage();

var htmlBody = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(your_html_string_in_variable, Encoding.UTF8,"text/html");

msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlBody);

IsBodyHtml = true;

... and do the rest of the stuff

Comment: I was add  smtp.Send(msg);
instead of

smtp.Send(mail.From, mail.To, mail.Subject, msg.Body); @vijay